# Transferring Wordpress Test Site from localhost to server

Tags: wordpress, backup

I need some help with Wordpress. I have developed a test website on localhost which I now need to transfer to a hosting server. I tried using akeeba backup but it is taking long time. Before that I also tried transferring files directly to the htaccess folder on the hosting website. It is taking lot of time. So please suggest some software or any other way I can fulfil my purpose. thanks in advance.

Comment: And what this question has to do with programming at all? I'm not even sure, if it fits to [Wordpress Development](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) (our sister project), but it certainly doesn't belong here. Off-topic completely, voting to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using the [WordPress Duplicator Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/). It's easy, and works almost every time.

When it doesn't work, you'll have to revert to the official method of doing migrations. WordPress has [a great overview of Moving WordPress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress) in the Codex, so I won't repeat it all here. In a nutshell, you'll need to:

> 1. Save your existing local site files.
> 2. Export your database - go in to mySQL and export the database.
> 3. Move the backed up files and database into a new folder - somewhere safe - this is your site backup.
> 4. Log in to the site you want to move (on your localhost) and go to Settings > General, then change the URLs. (ie from `http://localhost/` to
>      `http://example.net` ) - save the settings and expect to see a 404 page.
> 5. Save your local site files again.
> 6. Export the database again.
> 7. Edit wp-config.php with the new server's mySQL database name, user and password.
> 8. Upload the files.
> 9. Import the database on the new server.